# rails 3, how add a simple confirmation dialog when user clicks a link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, modal-dialog, confirmation

what is the easiest way in rails 3 to to ask "Are you sure you want to do that?" when the user clicks on a link?

the link in this case overwrites some data with a new value. It's a simple link_to (GET) back to the same controller method, with a param[] added.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**EDIT:**
 `<%= link_to "Do something", {:controller => "foo", :action => "bar"}, :confirm => "Are you sure you want to do that?" %>`

Answer (score 24):

For those like me that came here but are on Rails 4/5:

```
link_to "Title", some_path, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }
```

[The documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to-label-Data+attributes)

Answer (score 5):

There is a `:confirm` option:

```
link_to "Visit Other Site", "http://www.rubyonrails.org/", :confirm => "Are you sure?"
# => <a href="http://www.rubyonrails.org/" data-confirm="Are you sure?"">Visit Other Site</a>
```

You should have *unobtrusive JavaScript driver* like [this one](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs) for JQuery. It's pretty simple to setup.

Details are in [Rails API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to). 
For more details about UJS in Rails 3 you can follow [this tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/using-unobtrusive-javascript-and-ajax-with-rails-3/).

Answer (score 1):

If you use rails version 7 you can do it in this way:`link_to "Title", some_path, form: { data: { turbo_confirm: "Are you sure?" } }`