# Rails Confirm Delete Popup

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have a slight twist on the `Are you sure you want to delete this?` confirm popup.

`ruby-2.3.7`
`Rails 4.2.11.1`

I also have the `jquery-rails` gem.

When a certain link is clicked, I need to delete only about four fields in a record, not the entire record. That is working, but what I'd like to do is use a confirm pop up window when the link is clicked:  `Are you sure...?`

When the link is clicked I send the user to a `delete_interview_results` action in the controller, not a `destroy` or `delete` action.

I can create a view, redirect users there to have them confirm, but that doesn't seem like the best UI experience.

View:

```
<%= link_to 'Delete Interview Results',
             delete_interview_results_manage_applicant_path(@applicant), 
             class: 'btn',
             confirm: "Are you sure?" %>
```

Controller:

```
def delete_interview_results
    @applicant = Applicant.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to edit_manage_applicant_path(@applicant), notice: "You just deleted the interview results for #{@applicant.full_name}."
end
```

Routes:

```
resources :applicants, only: [ :edit, :update ] do
  ...
  get :delete_interview_results
  ...
end
```

I do not see any confirm popup window.  I thought having the `jquery-rails` gem did this.

When I add a `method: :delete` to this I get an error:

`No route matches [DELETE] "/manage/applicants/139289/delete_interview_results"`

Hopefully, I'm just missing a small piece.  I figure there has to be a way to do this.

Thanks for any tips n tricks.

Answer (score 2):

This worked: `data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }`

Found the answer here on StackOverflow:  [rails 3, how add a simple confirmation dialog when user clicks a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528641/rails-3-how-add-a-simple-confirmation-dialog-when-user-clicks-a-link)

It says rails3, but it worked for me in Rails 4.2.11

```
<%= link_to 'Delete Interview Results',
             delete_interview_results_manage_applicant_path(@applicant), 
             class: 'btn',
             data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>
```